# Vuforia + OBJ loader

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, android-ndk, vuforia

I am looking to use Vuforia for an AR project.

I understand that it utilises OpenGL ES and therefore typically uses arrays of vertex data to construct the object.

I want ot be able to use a standard OBJ file instead.

I already looked at using [this](http://heikobehrens.net/2009/08/27/obj2opengl/) but have no clue how to use a *.h file in the Android Java SDK.

So, I started looking at loading in an OBJ. I want to try and use something like [this](https://github.com/ldo/ObjViewer_Android) but just use the obj reader. But I'm stuck on how to get the vertex array.

Does anyone have knowledge on how to load an OBJ and pass it into the Vuforia Sample application?

(it needs to work in the Java SDK, not the NDK)

Comment: Did you solve this problem Mr. Pablo? I am stuck over the save thing and can't figure out how to proceed. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: We had one of our developers spill blood, sweat and tears creating a Rajawali + Vuforia wrapper that means you can load any model file Rajawali can use (OBJ or FBX typically). If we release it, I'll come back and let you know!

Comment: Please do release it @MrPablo! I'm going to be that developer in our company otherwise!

Comment: I'll speak to my boss about it. We completed the work (we needed ot use it for some client work) so I'll see what the plan is.

Answer (score -1):

.obj and openGL aren't directly compatible, openGL requires only 1 index for the vertices (all attributes get the same index) while .obj allows different indices for each attribute.

What that script does is pre-process the obj file so you can include it directly in the code without needing to (slowly) parse at runtime,

The equivalent java code of the .h file is:

```
package resource.models;

public class ModelName{

    public int  NumVerts = //exactly the number that is <name>NumVerts in the header

    public float[] Verts = {
        //copy paste the numbers and append f after each number like so:

        // f 1//2 7//2 5//2
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,
        0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,
        // f 1//2 3//2 7//2
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,
        -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,
        0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,

        //and so on
    }

    //repeat for Normals and textures:
    public float[] Normals = {
        // f 1//2 7//2 5//2
        0f, 0f, -1f,
        0f, 0f, -1f,
        0f, 0f, -1f,
        // f 1//2 3//2 7//2
        0f, 0f, -1f,
        0f, 0f, -1f,
        0f, 0f, -1f,

        //and so on
    }
}
```

To fill the openGL buffers you wrap the float arrays in `FloatBuffer`s and then pass them to the BufferData calls.

Changing the script in that article to be compatible with java requires changing the code from line [492](https://github.com/HBehrens/obj2opengl/blob/master/obj2opengl.pl#L492) to emit the package and class declaration and append an `f` after each number plus the trailing closing brace.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I was too clear. Ideally, I'd want to use a Java class to load the .obj in. I'd rather not use the .h file, as with a complex model the huge number of lines causes issues in Android Studio. I'd like to use the code in the second link, https://github.com/ldo/ObjViewer_Android but I'm not sure how exactly.

Comment: that code is not openGLSE20 ready, I suggest reading up on how to pass buffers to VBOs and drawing them as it's a big topic.

Comment: Ah ok. I have no experience with OpenGL and I need to get Vuforia working with an OBJ + MTL file. Going to keep digging to see if there is a Java library for this.

Comment: honestly I would prefer preprocessing the OBJ and putting it in a easy to read (aka. binary) format ready for exporting to VBOs.

Comment: Do you mean trying to go the .h file route? I would, but it seems I'd have to use the NDK and code it in C++, but this is dropping into an existing Java project. I'm barely any good at Java, let alone trying to figure out C++ :/

Comment: @MrPablo I mean include your own format where you first read the number of vertices and then read `count*4*3` bytes for the position and again `count*4*3` bytes for the normals. then just pass those into the VBOs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66932/discussion-between-mr-pablo-and-ratchet-freak).

Comment: Any solution guys ?